# I am not able to delete Item from the Todolist after executing model.findByIdAndDelete()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, web-applications, web-development-server

I want to delete an item from my database when I check the checkbox
Here is my `app.js` file code

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB");

const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model(
  "Item", itemsSchema
);

const defaultItem1 = new Item({
  name: "Welcome to your todolist!"
});
const defaultItem2 = new Item({
  name: "Hit the + button to add a new item."
});
const defaultItem3 = new Item({
  name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item."
});

const defaultItems = [defaultItem1, defaultItem2, defaultItem3];


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Item.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {  //Model.find({condition}, function (err, result){})

    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {

        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Items added successfully!");
        }
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    } else {
      res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
    }
  })
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  item.save();

  res.redirect("/");

});

app.post("/deleteItems", function (req, res){
  console.log(req.body.checkbox);
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  Item.findByIdAndDelete(checkedItemId, function (err){
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deleted checked item");
    }
  });
});


app.get("/work", function (req, res) {
  res.render("list", { listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems });
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

When I try to run above code, but I am not able to delete the particular item from the list

[Screenshot of Interface of the web app and server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mOnX.png)

and also if I try to check in my database, then the item is still present there

[Database Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgMpr.png)

And here is my `list.ejs` code

```html
<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1>
      <%= listTitle %>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <% newListItems.forEach(item=> { %>
      <form action="/deleteItems" method="post">
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id %> " onChange="this.form.submit()">
          <p>
            <%= item.name %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
      <% }); %>

        <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
          <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
        </form>
  </div>

  <%- include("footer") -%>
```

Comment: Do you see the "successfully deleted checked item" message in the console on your host side? Does the browser network window show the request returning successfully when you check a box?

Comment: no, I am not getting any acknowledgement on my console

Answer (score 0):

Yes i had the same issue for weeks and after so many frustration and time trying to find out while my code is not responding,I finally got where the issue is coming from ,its from the p tag which houses the item.name do make sure to cover it with a span tag and it will work, it did for me checkout the code below

```
    <%- include("header") -%>

<!-- Title Rendering -->
<div class="box" id="heading">
  <h1><%= listTitle %></h1>
</div>

<!-- Deleting an item using a checkbox -->

<div class="box">
  <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>

  <form action="/delete" method="post">
    <div class="item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="checkbox"
        value="<%= item._id %>"
        onChange="this.form.submit()"
      />
      <span><p><%= item.name %></p></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %> " />
  </form>
  <% }) %>

  <!-- New Item Rendering -->

  <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="newItem"
      placeholder="New Item"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %> ">+</button>
  </form>
</div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Comment: Thank you! After using your code I am successfully able to delete the items

Comment: Your are welcome very glad to hear this it keeps me going . Happy Coding